# What is the proper way to insert academicons in an R blogdown post (`icon::ai("GitHub")` interferes with share header icons)?

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

I am using R blogdown with the hugo-academic theme and love Yihui's work (and naturally the theme).

I inserted acidemicons in a post using the icon package (`https://github.com/ropenscilabs/icon`), e.g.,

```
- [Mendeley `r icon::ai("mendeley")`](https://www.mendeley.com)
```

Unfortunately, this somehow clashes with the icons in the share header (only the envelope/email icon shows up and the remaining do not, i.e., twitter, facebook and linkedin). In other posts with no `icon::ai()` calls the header is fine.

Here is the post with the call (note the share icons at the top right are greyed out)

https://racinejs.netlify.com/post/academic-networks-public-profiles/

Here is a post without (note the share icons at the top right are well formed)

https://racinejs.netlify.com/post/github-education-and-private-repositories/

So, I am guessing there is an alternate way to include the academicons in the R blogdown/R markdown post that does not rely on the icon package, but my unfamiliarity with this framework is working against me. I have been unable to dig up any other way of successfully doing this hence my post.

The GitHub repository for the site can be found at https://github.com/JeffreyRacine/static-hugo-site in case this is helpful.

So, if by chance you know the proper way to do this I would be most grateful.

Thanks in advance for your efforts and suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps others, after all that some experimenting and looking at the theme code revealed that

```
<i class="ai ai-mendeley"></i>
```

is all that is needed and resolves the issue.